# Using GORM to retrieve tables names from Postgresql

Tags: go, go-gorm

Looking to retrieve table names from my postgresql database. Now, I know in Go you can use sql and the pq driver, but I'm using GORM for doing queries in my REST API.

The table_name type in PostgreSQL is "information_schema.sql_identifier". This is what I was trying to do, but the type isn't string.

```
var tables []string
if err := db.Table("information_schema.tables").Select("table_name").Where("table_schema = ?", "public").Find(&tables).Error; err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: …so, what type is it?

Comment: It's showing up as "information_schema.sql_identifer" for the type for the table names. I was looking to make it a string.

Comment: That's the type internal to PostgreSQL, right? It's [right there in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/infoschema-tables.html). So what's the type GORM maps it to? I've assumed from your question that unmarshaling of the query results into a slice of strings, `[]string`, fails with some sort of an error about type mismatch, but you did not tell us which exactly for some reason. Is this true?

Comment: Please make us not excercise in "guesseneering"; if an alleged solution fails, the question should include exact error messges. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That is not how Gorm works. You might want to check the `db.Pluck` function.

Comment: @DatNgo Using db.Pluck did work. In terms of solution, I would make it an official comment, as it did work for me.

Comment: I was just too lazy to post the official answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To select a single column values into a slice using Gorm, you can use `db.Pluck` helper:

```golang
var tables []string
if err := db.Table("information_schema.tables").Where("table_schema = ?", "public").Pluck("table_name", &tables).Error; err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**TS;WM**

Considering this, the SELECT statement returns a set of rows with one or more columns. In order to map those to Go code, we need a sort of struct so that Gorm can understand which column is mapped to which field of the struct. Even when you only select 1 single column, it's just a struct with 1 single field.

```golang
type Table struct {
    TableName   string
    // more fields if needed...
}
```

So your output variable should be `[]*Table`:

```golang
var tables []*Table
if err := db.Table("information_schema.tables").Select("table_name").Where("table_schema = ?", "public").Find(&tables).Error; err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Note: it could be `[]Table` as well if you don't want to modify the element inside the slice.

If you don't want to define the struct, you can use the the `db.Pluck` function which is just a helper of this sort of code:

```golang
rows, err := db.Table("information_schema.tables").Select("table_name").Where("table_schema = ?", "public").Rows()
defer rows.Close()

var tables []string
var name string
for rows.Next() {
    row.Scan(&name)
    tables = append(tables, name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you're trying to do this with sqllite like I was, the following code will do it

```
var tables []string
if err := logic.DB().Table("sqlite_master").Where("type = ?", "table").Pluck("name", &tables).Error; err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```